# How can I get rid of "id" parameter when using extra_actions in Django-Tastypie?

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm using Django-Tastypie for building RESTful API. I'm using [extra actions](https://github.com/concentricsky/django-tastypie-swagger) to have more actions. When I pass `http_method` as  **GET**, I get an `id` field which in some cases I require, but in some I dont require it because I want to get all results in some and specific filtered results in some.

So, when I need all the results, the `id` parameter should not be there. And when I need filtered results it should be there(which it is there already). So, my question is How can I remove `id` field when I require all the results?

It is written there that

> If resource_type is declared as "list" then the endpoint will not include a `{id}` parameter in the uri or in the parameters list. This is applicable to endpoints such as the above example that filter or perform actions across many items. If resource_type is ommitted and the http_method is "GET" then the endpoint will default to "view" and include a `{id}` parameter in the uri and parameter list.

But this is in the case of URI's only, it still requires an id field, even if I declare `resouce_type` as `list`.

Here are the screen-shots:-

When `resouce_type` declared as `list`. Look there's no `{id}` in the URI. But I want that in the fields there should be no **id**.

[image: When <code>resouce_type</code> declared as <code>list</code>]

How can I do that?

Also, I'm facing **another issue**. I've a field which is related to another field via `ManyToManyField` relation, which means I need to provide a LIST of values to that field. But it doesn't take a LIST, instead it takes a string value itself. I've uploaded the screen-shot for that itself. Please let me know the hack of this. Thanks.

In this case `installation_id` is related via `ManyToManyField`. It shows `related` but instead I want that it should accept a list of values(`installation_id`). How can I do that?

[image]

And **WHY** does delete doesn't have an id? I mean it shows `id` but doesn't have a field to enter anything.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a spare minute right now but I think that's my code so I'll star this question and come back at it in a couple hours.

Comment: Can you post the `extra_actions` dict?

Comment: Looks like you found a bug! See my answer below for how to clone the repo and make that change. I'll open an issue on the repo for this one.

Comment: Issue [#49](https://github.com/concentricsky/django-tastypie-swagger/issues/49) opened for this.

Answer (score 0):

The way `extra_actions` and the `list` vs `view` type is implemented is all inside `mapping.py`.

Here are two sample `extra_actions` endpoints, one describes a search view (`list`) and the other is a POST endpoint for bidding with a `pk` parameter required.

```
extra_actions = [
    {
        "name": "search",
        "http_method": "GET",
        "resource_type": "list",
        "summary": "Search item listings",
        "response_class": "ListView",
        "fields": {
            "query": {
                "description": "Search terms"
            }
        },
    },
    {
        "name": "bid",
        "http_method": "POST",
        "resource_type": "view",
        "summary": "Bid on an item listing",
        "fields": {
            "name": {
                "description": "Bid on an item"
            },
            "email": {
                "description": "Bidder's email address"
            },
            "comments": {
                "description": "Notes or comments about the bid"
            },
            "bid": {
                "description": "Amount in USD or BTC"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

For compatibility reasons `extra_actions` defaults to `view` as seen in `mapping.py` under the `build_extra_operation` function. The parameters are built from the `build_parameters_from_extra_action` copied below:

```
def build_parameters_from_extra_action(self, method, fields, resource_type):
    parameters = []
    if method.upper() == 'GET' or resource_type == "view":
        parameters.append(self.build_parameter(paramType='path',
            name=self._detail_uri_name(),
            dataType='int',
            description='ID of resource'))
    for name, field in fields.items():
        parameters.append(self.build_parameter(
            paramType="query",
            name=name,
            dataType=field.get("type", "string"),
            required=field.get("required", True),
            description=force_unicode(field.get("description", "")),
        ))

    return parameters
```

I *think* there's an issue with this as I'm going through it. The check is `if method.upper() == 'GET' or resource_type == "view":` not `if method.upper() == 'GET' and resource_type == "view":` or the more shorter and possibly more correct `if resource_type == "view":`.

I would recommend cloning a copy of the repo and making this modification locally. I'll go through and see what that check modification will break. I noticed that the `id` parameter is showing up as required in my views as well.

Comment: I'll try and see what can be done. In the meanwhile, if you (or me) found a hack to get this through, please post it here or anywhere else. Thanks

Comment: Also, I'm facing another issue. I've a field which is related to another field via `ManyToManyField` relation, which means I need to provide a LIST of values to that field. But it doesn't take a LIST, instead it takes a string value itself. I've uploaded the screen-shot for that itself. Please let me know the hack of this. Thanks.